# ML.NET and Model Builder Local or Remote

Tags: ml.net

When we use Model Builder and the ML.NET to build models are the computations done on the host machine or does the data get sent to an Azure service that performs the computations to generate the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all done locally, but the Image Classification selection has an option to do the training in Azure. You can check this for future updates by the "Local ML" or "Azure ML" tags on each of the items near the bottom.

[image]